# How can I add global (usable outside of Emacs) hotkeys?

Tags: key-bindings, microsoft-windows

Several applications like Mumble allow the use of *global* hotkeys that even get intercepted if Mumble is not in focus at the time of the key press.

Is there a way within Emacs to create such shortcuts, for example to immediately invoke `org-capture` via <kbd>Super-C</kbd>? Or do I need to use an external application such as AutoHotkey?

(If the functionality requires a specific operating system or Desktop environment: I'm on Windows 10)

Answer (score 2):

It generally requires listening to *all* keystrokes all the time, and swearing profusely that you’re not a keylogger. And naturally the way you implement it is quite different from OS to OS. It therefore cannot be done directly in Emacs lisp; it requires some level of C programming to integrate with the OS.

I don’t believe that anyone has implemented this integration, but I could be wrong. In any case, if you want to try it the source is readily available. If you don’t want to modify Emacs directly, know that Emacs does have the ability to load pluggable modules; you could write one of those instead. You should read [chapter 16.11 Emacs Dynamic Modules](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Dynamic-Modules.html) from the Emacs Lisp Manual for more information.